# HTML5 AUDIO Loop through different sources perpetually

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Hello I'm having a very hard time looping through different audio players. I've tried all sorts of methods starting with what I thought was elegant: Switching the src on one player and loading new src and playing. Each time it refused to work so my revisions have gotten cruder to the point of now trying 4 seperate audio players At this point all I care about is getting this damn thing to work.

```
var ear = document.getElementById('ear'),
    ogg = document.getElementById('ogg'),
    mp3 = document.getElementById('mp3'),
    sounds = ['laughing', 'gull', 'reel', 'snore'],
    counter = 0,
    loop = 0,
    activate = 0,
    p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

function loopPrep(){
   audio.remove();
   for (var i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++) {
            var elem =
                        "<source id='ogg' src=media/"+sounds[i]+".ogg type='audio/ogg'>"+
                        "<source id='mp3' src=media/"+sounds[i]+'.mp3 type="audio/mpeg">';
           var temp = document.createElement('audio');
           document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(temp);
           var a = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[i];
           a.innerHTML=elem;
       }; 
        document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].addEventListener('onended', function(){ document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[1].play(); });  
      document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[1].addEventListener('onended', function(){  document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[2].play(); });
      document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[2].addEventListener('onended', function(){  document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[3].play(); });
      document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[3].addEventListener('onended', function(){ document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play(); });
       document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play();
              };


function playNext(){
    if (counter == 3){
        loop = 1; activate = 1; loopPrep();
    } else { counter++; };
    ogg.setAttribute('src', 'media/'+sounds[counter]+".ogg");
    mp3.setAttribute('src', 'media/'+sounds[counter]+".mp3");
}
```

Comment: Figured it out - I was writing onended instead of ended for my event listeners. This turned out to be the problem from the very beginning. Good eye on the ID's though.

Comment: Your idea of using multiple audio elements is the best one, except if you really need to show the original reader in the page. Some UAs don't cache audio medias, so if you do change the src of a single audio element, they will make a new call to the file. Also, try to use your variables instead of calling DOM methods each time (`getElementsByTagName`, `getElementById`)

Comment: ah yeah your right on that I should move those up into the loop and use the cached var

Answer (score -1):

I realized that my event listeners were 'onended' and should have been 'ended'. onended is for inline html execution.

Time to go back and rewrite it with one audio player and switching the src and load and play.